# Submitted and Authorized Invoice in Xero Api

Tags: xero-api

I am try to Create Invoice in Xero using asp.net and i set Invoice Status Authorized and type ACCREC but I cant create it throw "The tax type field is mandatory" How to rectify this problem

Comment: What are you putting in for the Tax Type? It seems that in my code (which is a bit old now, so I don't completely remember) any line item that has an item code also has a tax type.

Comment: TaxType is referring to the TaxType field on the LineItems within the invoice.  You need to specify a TaxType: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/types#tax-types. TaxTypes depend on the region of the org, so you can retrieve them programatically via the TaxRates endpoint: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/taxrates